# Starts a Task after a Task runs 5 times

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement, task

I want to start a task after my tasks have gone through five times.
Is this possible in a simple way?
I can't do that with a simple timer because my customers set the time in the tasks themselves. When I set a timer, the task that is supposed to start after the fifth round starts at the wrong time.

I have a program whose tasks (8 tasks) start and end one after the other. The last task then starts the first again. and I somehow need a counter that counts when the fifth round is over. So the last task must be completed for the fifth time, then this one specific task that I want to include should switch on automatically and if they is done then start the first one itself.

**this is my async tasks.. it starts with button and repeats.. its only a minimized version.**

```
async void STARTCLICK(CancellationToken token)
    {
      
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            

            try
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                await Task.Delay(100, token);                   

                if ()
                {
                    
                }
            }
            catch (AggregateException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Expected");
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Bug");
            }
            catch { }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        var t2 = Task.Run(() => START(token));
        await Task.WhenAny(new[] { t2 });
    }

    async void START(CancellationToken token)
    {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            try
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                await Task.Delay(100, token);             

                if ()
                {
                  
                }

            }
            catch (AggregateException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Expected");
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bug");
            }
            catch { }


        }
        Thread.Sleep(7000);

        
        var t3 = Task.Run(() => MOVE(token));
        await Task.WhenAny(new[] { t3 });
    }
    
    async void MOVE(CancellationToken token)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {

           
            try
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                await Task.Delay(100, token);
           
                if ()
                {
                    
                }

            }
            catch (AggregateException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Expected");
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bug");
            }
            catch { }

        }
        var t4 = Task.Run(() => RESTART(token));
        await Task.WhenAny(new[] { t4 });

    }
            async void RESTART(CancellationToken token)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {

           
            try
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                await Task.Delay(100, token);
           
                if ()
                {
                    
                }

            }
            catch (AggregateException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Expected");
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bug");
            }
            catch { }

        }
        var t4 = Task.Run(() => STARTCLICK(token));
        await Task.WhenAny(new[] { t4 });
```

**is it possible to script it like this? REPAIR is the Task that i need only each 5th time... i need the token canccelation in my tasks. because the Tasks are very big and schould be stopped anytime.
Repair is a Task between EXITACCEPT and RESTART.**
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: my post is edited :)

Comment: As a side note, the liberal use if `async void` in your code is not a good practice. Check out this article for more details: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Comment: So you have four asynchronous methods (`STARTCLICK`, `START`, `MOVE`, and `RESTART`) that each one calls the other in a never-ending recursive loop, and each method contains an inner `for` loop with a predefined number of iterations. I assume that this inner `for` loop is irrelevant to your problem. Do you want to inject the fifth asynchronous method whenever the outer recursive loop has been completed 5 times?

Comment: Exactly, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please never ever code `catch { }`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I'm glad you've understood this, as I'm lost. Can you explain what the OP is doing?

Comment: @Enigmativity each asynchronous method starts the next asynchronous method just before its completion. At least this must be the intention. The `Thread.Sleep`/`async void` shenanigans indicate that something more chaotic might be actually happening.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Yeah, that I got from the code. I want to understand what the OP is trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: @Enigmativity it's probably some kind of background processing, that goes on during the whole lifetime of the application. I didn't ask what exactly is this processing, because it's probably not important for the core problem.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I think it's important. Providing a good design is better than fixing a bad design.

Comment: @Enigmativity I agree. That's why I suggested an alternative, simpler, design in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71653919/starts-a-task-after-a-task-runs-5-times/71654573#71654573)! Feel free to ask the OP for any clarifications/details that you deem as important, in order to provide a better answer. :-)

Comment: use a global variable to count task iterations, do something when it reaches 5 then reset it.  Old school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you have implemented the infinite recursive loop is a bit sketchy. It should be quite difficult to maintain it. My suggestion is to remove the dependencies/interactions between the asynchronous methods, and delegate the responsibility of calling them in a looping fashion to a "master" asynchronous method, that invokes them sequentially in a `while` loop:

```
async Task InfiniteLoopAsync()
{
    long iteration = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        iteration++;
        await Method_A();
        await Method_B();
        await Method_C();
        await Method_D();
        if (iteration % 5 == 0) await Method_E();
    }
}
```

Each of the methods should have a `Task` return type, not `void`:

```
async Task Method_A()
{
}
```

Finally you can start the infinite loop like this:

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await InfiniteLoopAsync();
}
```

The `Click` event handler should be your only method with [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) signature.

Comment: wow its crazy, I thank you so much. you nailed it :) 
but is it still reliable to end the tasks via cancellation token? because the while runs through, doesn't it? it was very important to me to be able to stop quickly between processes

Comment: @Steven you can inject either `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` or `if (token.IsCancellationRequested) break;` lines in various places inside the infinite loop. Or even better just allow the `OperationCanceledException` that is thrown inside the methods to propagate to the `InfiniteLoopAsync` method, and then `try`/`catch` and suppress this exception inside the `Click` handler.

Comment: @Steven just replace the `t7` variable with `Task.Run(() => REPAIR(token))` directly. It seems that you don't need this variable somewhere else in your code. The purpose of `Task.WhenAny(new[] { t })` is somewhat mysterious, but I guess that you have some good reason to have it there.

Comment: @Steven or add a code block `{ }` after the `if (iteration % 5 == 0)` statement, and put the code that runs the `t7` task inside the block. This way you can run conditionally more than one lines of code. See [The `if` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-if-statement).

Comment: ye but i got the problem that my GUI is frozen... any idea why this happens? i never had the problem before this solution

Comment: @Steven most probably you have a `.Wait()` or `.Result` somewhere. Take a look at this: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). If you don't find a solution in this article, my suggestion is to post a new question regarding this particular freezing problem, including a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SemaphoreSlim` with a max count of 5. This means a maximum of 5 threads can enter this semaphore at once. Once all five is consumed, perform the special task and release 5 threads on the semaphore. Rinse and repeat.

Here is an example. Warning: the `TaskRepeater` class is faulty (e.g. exception handling).

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

var taskRepeater = new TaskRepeater(async () => await RepeatedTaskAsync(), 5);

await taskRepeater.RunAsync(async () => await RegularTaskAsync("A"));
await taskRepeater.RunAsync(async () => await RegularTaskAsync("B"));
await taskRepeater.RunAsync(async () => await RegularTaskAsync("C"));
await taskRepeater.RunAsync(async () => await RegularTaskAsync("D"));
await taskRepeater.RunAsync(async () => await RegularTaskAsync("E"));
await taskRepeater.RunAsync(async () => await RegularTaskAsync("F"));
await taskRepeater.RunAsync(async () => await RegularTaskAsync("G"));
await taskRepeater.RunAsync(async () => await RegularTaskAsync("H"));
await taskRepeater.RunAsync(async () => await RegularTaskAsync("I"));
await taskRepeater.RunAsync(async () => await RegularTaskAsync("J"));
await taskRepeater.RunAsync(async () => await RegularTaskAsync("K"));

static async Task RepeatedTaskAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running repeated task.");
    await Task.Delay(500);
}

static async Task RegularTaskAsync(string id)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Running regular task {id}.");
    await Task.Delay(50);
}

public class TaskRepeater
{
    private readonly int frequency;
    private readonly Func<Task> repeatTaskFactory;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim repeatSemaphore;
    
    public TaskRepeater(Func<Task> repeatTaskFactory, int frequency)
    {
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.repeatTaskFactory = repeatTaskFactory;
        this.semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(frequency, frequency);
        this.repeatSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    }
    
    public async Task RunAsync(Func<Task> taskFactory)
    {
        try
        {
            await this.semaphore.WaitAsync();
            await taskFactory.Invoke();
            
            if (this.semaphore.CurrentCount == 0 && this.repeatSemaphore.CurrentCount != 0)
            {
                await this.PerformRepeatedTaskAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (this.semaphore.CurrentCount == 0)
            {
                this.semaphore.Release();
            }
            
            if (this.repeatSemaphore.CurrentCount > 0)
            {
                this.repeatSemaphore.Release();
            }
            
            throw;
        }
    }
    
    private async Task PerformRepeatedTaskAsync()
    {
        await this.repeatSemaphore.WaitAsync();
                
        if (this.semaphore.CurrentCount > 0)
        {
            this.repeatSemaphore.Release();
            return;
        }

        await this.repeatTaskFactory.Invoke();

        this.semaphore.Release(frequency);
        this.repeatSemaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Running regular task A.
Running regular task B.
Running regular task C.
Running regular task D.
Running regular task E.
Running repeated task.
Running regular task F.
Running regular task G.
Running regular task H.
Running regular task I.
Running regular task J.
Running repeated task.
Running regular task K.
```